# Efficient initial sync with SyncFolderItems in EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, microsoft-exchange

I am writing a client application that tracks emails and calendar events from exchange servers. Currently I am getting the initial state of the users' inbox folders with SyncFolderItems with IdOnly set to True.

Is there a more efficient way to get the initial state of the users' folders without having to repeatedly call SyncFolderItems?